# Resources to find out how to best experience a game

Tags: mods, version-differences

When choosing a new (to me, I usually play titles that have been out for some years) game to play I always have questions like these.

- Are there censored / crippled versions of the game?
- If it's available on multiple hardware platforms what are the pros and cons of each one?
- Are there particular steps to take to make it run properly on modern hardware / operating systems?
- What is the latest patch? If the game isn't actively supported anymore where can I find it?
- Are there unofficial mods that are strongly suggested?

As you can see this is geared towards PCs but I'm also interested in consoles.

The usually way that I go about this is to ask search engines. Then I come up with reviews on sites like Steam and GOG, Wikipedia pages, fan sites / forums, official sites (if still available) and the such.

I don't particularly mind this process but I'm always worried about spoilers and missing out some important details.

So, I was wondering if there are some resources (like an "internet game DB") where I could reliably find out these details about games.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[PCGamingWiki](https://www.pcgamingwiki.com/) does exactly what you ask for.
Except for finding out which platform it's best experienced on. It only consists of information regarding the PC version, and how to improve it.

Comment: It will be very useful, thanks.